# How can I get the location(city,country.. ) from HttpServletRequest using spring boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, postman

I want to know the location from httpServletRequest. Is there any way to do that?
I want to use one of  the getters methods of httpServletRequest like getRemoteAddr()..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean with location : city and country

Comment: Well, requests don't include a physical address by default. Unless your client actively sends this information to you. What it does include is an IP address. There are online services that allow you to guess the country and often the city based on that.

Comment: @Hulk Ok thanks .And if i want to get source, which method i should to use

Comment: @Sarah What did you mean of *source*?

Comment: @RasoolGhafari I mean Navigator web, navigator mobile or web application

Comment: I suggest you to read this posts: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-new-device-location and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mobile

Answer (score 1):

This looks old post. For upcoming visitors adding this answer.

Try to use `httpServletRequest.getLocale().getCountry()` this will return country name as string.

Another option to get more precise values like ISO3 country code, ISO language codes use below methods
Pass the HttpServletRequest object to RequestContext(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext)

```
RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(httpServletRequest);
String countryISO3 = requestContext.getLocale().getISO3Country();
```

It has many methods.